# Separation of concern. Accessor methods and data sanitisation.

Tags: php, separation-of-concerns

I have a great deal of 'dirty' data pulled from an API request.

Before database insertion, I clean out a lot of line feeds and regex out values such as height and width from item descriptions.

This is my first large project as a software engineer, and I would like to leave something coherent for future developers.

Here is one such example:

```
private function lineItemHeight($invoiceLineItem)
{
    if(preg_match("/(\d+mm W)|(\d+mm H)/", $invoiceLineItem, $matches) == 1)
    {
        $height = $matches[1];
        return preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $height);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And another:

```
private function contactName()
{
    // Removes appended (email@address.sample) from contact name
    return preg_replace('/\([^)]*\)/', "", $this->contactName);
}
```

Would I be better off having a `SanatiseInvoiceData` class to parse all the strings before they are set, or is my current practice acceptable.

I am looking for industry or expected standard.  What I have works -not knowing how well it stands up to scrutiny makes me uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing records is a bread and butter programming problem, and there are at least a dozen ways to do it.

The way that has always seemed the clearest to me, when maintaining very old code, is when the programmer takes the trouble to define a class that represents a record or row *itself* (e.g. a `Record` class, not a `RecordParser` class). That means a stateful class. Might look like this:

```
class SanatisedInvoiceLineItem {
    private $text;

    function __construct($originalText) {
        $this->text = $originalText;
    }

   function getHeight()
   {
       if(preg_match("/(\d+mm W)|(\d+mm H)/", $this->text, $matches) !== 1)
       {
           return 0;
       }
       $height = $matches[1];
       return preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $height);
    }  
}
```

To use it:

```
$line = new SanitisedInvoiceLineItem($textFromApi);
$height = $line=>getHeight();
```

Couple notes:

1. The class naturally provides a namespace, so your function names can get shorter (`getHeight` instead of `lineItemHeight`).
2. You can validate the entire line item in the constructor, if you want. This may be more suitable than validating each field separately.